# Add file upload button in CompanyCommunicator newMessage

Tags: reactjs, typescript, microsoft-teams, tsx

There is a Microsoft template called [CompanyCommunicator](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-apps-company-communicator), me being a C# dev not able to figure out TSX React and TS. Can someone help on this? Exact component [newMessage Module URL](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-apps-company-communicator/tree/master/Source/CompanyCommunicator/ClientApp/src/components/NewMessage)

Need to add file upload button instead of image URL. User will upload a image and that sits on blob and generates anonymous access URL. Just need to figure out how to add UploadFile button.

Comment: The button is declared in [blob](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-apps-company-communicator/blob/de2520965d5cff88eb382f5254ac69a793e9386e/Source/CompanyCommunicator/ClientApp/src/components/AdaptiveCard/adaptiveCard.ts#L86), in new message module the button is set please check [this](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-apps-company-communicator/blob/master/Source/CompanyCommunicator/ClientApp/src/components/NewMessage/newMessage.tsx#L162), Is that you are looking for? try if that helps.

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT I'm looking for configuring file upload button in newMessage module for image URL. Right now, we will have to paste the image URL. How to put file upload button that allows from local machine instead of we pasting the URL?

Comment: Are you using bot or tab to upload a file?

Comment: @akill Are you still facing an issue?

Comment: @akil - could you please update?

Answer (score 0):

You can upload a new button which is used to upload an image using a URL, here to add button to new message adaptive card is used. Could you please check this [sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-apps-company-communicator/blob/master/Source/CompanyCommunicator/ClientApp/src/components/NewMessage/newMessage.tsx#L162)